# How to get the heap usage of a single thread at runtime within the same application?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

I would like to measure the heap usage of a specific Thread from within the app that creates it.
That app is multi-threaded and has other threads that I am not interested in measuring.

**Please do not point me at profilers or other external reporting tools**. I am only interested in code I can run at runtime within the same application.

If possible I am looking to something similar to using `ThreadMXBean` to measure CPU time. If there is such a solution I have not found (and I have been searching for a while).

Also is there a way to know which memory pools a thread is using? I was thinking of using something similar to

```
HashSet<String> poolNames = getUsedPoolNames(thisThread);
long heapUsage = 0L;
for(MemoryPoolMXBean bean: ManagementFactory.getMemoryPoolMXBeans()) {
    if(poolNames .contains(bean.getName()){
       heapUsage += bean.getHeapUsage().getUsage().getUsed();
    }
}
```

Would something like this work? What would `getUsedPoolNames(~)` look like?
How are memory pools and thread linked?

Comment: Package `org.hyperic.sigar` provide you all api with these stuff and support a lot of OS.

Comment: [org.hyperic.sigar](http://www.hyperic.com/support/docs/sigar/org/hyperic/sigar/package-summary.html) provide you with most of the information in a PC

Comment: How can I get the memory of one specific thread in my java application using `org.hyperic.sigar`??? It seems to be as general as using `Runtime`'s `freeMemory()` and `totalMemory()` methods.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's something at the API level that will get you that.  Not easily, anyways.  Memory's not really reserved against threads.  Memory is reserved against objects, and objects are not thread-specific.

There is a nifty tool out there that can do all this by parsing memory dumps, but I'm not sure if it works against a live JVM.

What you would need to do is find the objects associated with the threead (not sure how to do that) and then navigate its references to calculate the retained heap (as the memory being used is more than just the the object itself, but also the objects whose references being held also take up memory.  This is not a trivial task.  And you're not going to get it from a simple API call.  Plus, it's not really thread-specific, as another thread could have references to the same objects (as objects can be used by multiple threads.

Part of this is difficult because threads/objects are meant to be ignorant about the memory pools.  That's something for the JVM to manage.

So, um, dunno.

Comment: +1 - threads must have a private stack, but are not obliged to have a private heap.